# Half Adder and Two Function, A Contest Questions?

Tags: digital-logic, math, logic-gates, adder, decoder

I ran into a 2013 contest question on computer-science filed.

What is the following True about `F` and `G` function. (The output of Decoder is zero when disabled).

> I) Is equal.
>
> II) Complement to each other.
>
> III) the `1's` in F is more than `1's` in G.
>
> IV) the `0's` in F is more than `0's` in G.

Answer Sheet Select (1), But I think (2) is Correct. Who can verify me and hint how we can correctly solve such a circuit?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the decoder is active, the Truth table is as follows :

```
XZ    Dec_Out    HA1        HA2    a b cin    F G
               Sum | C    Sum | C
00   1000      1     0    0     0  1 1 0      0 1
01   0100      1     0    0     0  1 1 0      0 1
10   0010      0     0    1     0  0 1 1      0 1
11   0001      0     0    1     0  0 1 1      0 1
```

The truth table is easy to construct :

- First determine the output of decoder corresponding to various inputs
- Next apply D0 and D1 as inputs to HA1 and D2 and D3 as inputs to HA2
- Compute their outputs and apply them to FA

Now since it was a competition problem, there has to be a short cut (which I was not able to figure out initially as well) instead of solving the truth table :P

- Two outputs of a decoder cant be simultaneously high. This means that the sum of both half adders cant be one simultaneously. Infact, output of exactly one HA HAS to be 1 always, and also that both have to give a carry of zero.
- The Xnor will always give a 1, since both carry are always zero.
- If 2 of the inputs to the Full adder are always one, the sum ie F will always be 0, while the carry ie G will always be 1.

Similar arguments hold when decoder is inactive, but this time output of both HA will be 0.

- With outputs of both half adders as zero, the XNOR is still high while A and Cin are zero
- So the input of FA consists of exactly one, which means sum ie F will always be 1 while carry ie G will always be 0.

In either case, F and G are always complements to each other.

Comment: Complete answer, your means which one is True /

Comment: The second option most definitely !

Comment: is it possible make your answer a bit clearer?

Comment: What part is not clear ?

Comment: why III and IV is not true ?

Comment: +1, but I Think it's can be ever simpler and more detail. would you please :)